# How to design a CNN in Keras for data of dimensions (2505,10)?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am designing a neural network for the classification of resting-state EEG signals. I have preprocessed my data such that each subject is characterized by a table consisting of 111 channels and their readings over 2505 timesteps. As a measure of dimensionality reduction, I clustered the 111 channels into the 10 lobes of the brain, effectively reducing the dimension to (2505,10) per subject. Since this data is 2D, I assume it would be analogous to CNNs for grayscale images.

I have compiled the EEG data for each subject into a dataframe of size (253, 2505, 10), where 253 is the number of subjects. The corresponding ground truth values are stored in a list of size (253,1) with the indices matching those from the dataframe. I want to build a classifier which tells if the subject is ADHD positive or negative. I am stuck on designing the neural network, particularly facing a dimensionality issue when passing a subject to the 1st layer.

```
#where        X=[df0, df1, df2,......, df252]    &    y=[0,1,0,........,1]

# Model configuration
batch_size = 100
no_epochs = 30
learning_rate = 0.001
no_classes = 2
validation_split = 0.2
verbosity = 1

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit data to model
i=0 #validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
print("X_train:\t")
print(X_train.shape)
print("y_train:\t")
print(y_train.shape)

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train, 
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=no_epochs,
              verbose=verbosity)
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_12 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2505, 10).

Any help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a Conv2D model your train data, in an image processing perspective, needs to be of 4 dimension (N_observatoion, nrows, ncolumns, nchannels). Therefore, you have to reshape your features accordingly as per your domain knowledge to make it meaningful:

```
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(253, 2505, 10, 1) or # np.array(X_train).reshape(253, 2505, 1, 10) 
# Then models can be defined as following:
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape = X_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
```

I dont have any experience working with Signal data but what I would like to share that if your channel columns do not have any spatial significance like that in an image pixel then considering a 2D Conv network is not meaningful. For example if among 111 channels putting channel X's data in column 1 or putting channel Y's data in column 1 doesnt have any meaningful difference like that of the opposite in case of an image pixels then your sliders of a conv2D is not getting any significant information. Rather you can consider a conv1D or LSTM networks. for a conv 1D network you dont need 4 dimension X and your corrent 3 dimension X is ok. You can Try:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape = X_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance. I managed to overcome that issue, however, now I'm facing a different issue. I pass the X_train and y_train variables into model.fit() but I get an "InvalidArgumentError: Logits and labels must have the same first dimension. Got logits shape [12520, 64] and labels shape [10].  I must mention that X_train consists of 169 instances (subjects) out of the total of 253. I have chosen a batch size of 10. I have searched the error on google but I am not able to understand how the system got the logits shape [12520, 64]. I am still trying to proceed with 2DConv.

Comment: If your y has only 2 category then you can try with binary cross entropy loss and your network should end with a single node. But if you have 10 categories then you need to have a y_train as a matrix of order 10X1 and your network has to have 10 nodes in the end. You can add a few dense layer at the end to achieve that

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, it worked! I added more layers into the network and ended the network with the dense layer with a single node.

Comment: Welcome, and so I guess you can accept and vote my answer so that I gain some reputation as I am a new contributor and dont have much